# How to write characteristics for bluetooth gatt service for two channels without getting disconnected(state 133)?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I've a bluetooth gatt service and two channels to write

```
bluetoothGattService = gatt?.getService(UUID.fromString(ble_gatt_service_uuid))

mTxCharacteristic1 = bluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(txCharacteristics1))
mTxCharacteristic2 = bluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(txCharacteristics2))
```

Now I have `onCharacteristicsRead()`, `onCharacteristicsWrite()`, and `onCharacteristicsChange()`

I connected with the ble device

When I write on `mTxCharacteristic1` characteristic then ble works well

But whenever I write on `mTxCharacteristic2` characteristic then ble gets `DISCONNECTED`

```
// function1
mTxCharacteristic1.writeType = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE
mTxCharacteristic1.value = chunk
gatt.writeCharacteristic(mTxCharacteristic1)

//function 2
mTxCharacteristic2.writeType = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT
mTxCharacteristic2.value = chunk
gatt.writeCharacteristic(mTxCharacteristic2)
```

How to resolve this?

Everytime it is getting disconnected whenever I send data using 2nd characteristics, I'm only able to connect with ble again only when I restart my android device.

I tried:

```
gatt.beginReliableWrite()           
gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic1,true)
gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic1)
gatt.executeReliableWrite()
```

```
gatt.beginReliableWrite()
gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic2,true)
gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic2)
gatt.executeReliableWrite()
```

[nrf connect app showing (TX(1) and unknown_characteristic(2))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swsHe.jpg)

still getting the same disconnected with gatt server issue with state 133.

Comment: Are you sure both characteristics allow writing? I see you enable notifications on the second characteristic. This seems to be a readable characteristic

Comment: yes both allow writing

Comment: Have you tested writing using a generic BLE app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)? Your device might need some specific message on the first before allowing writing to the second

Comment: Let me try with nrf app will update this

Comment: Thanks for the update. You state you see TX and unknown characteristic but there is also a RX characteristic that allows notifications but no write. Please check that you use the correct UUIDs, only write to TX and only activate notifications on RX. You can activate notifications in nRF Connect as well to test the correct receiving by clicking the symbol of multiple downward arrows next to the characteristic when connected.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKotzjan it helped me to debug it, the issue I got to know was I was sending improper length data packet than expected which was reason of disconnection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made this simple `writeCharacteristics` instead of `reliableWrite` on doing this disconnection and no repairing issue resolved

`gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic1)`

`gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic2)`

I was have 8 byte of packet data where I sent null which I found on debugging

expected was 19 byte array and I was sending only 11 packets (8 missed)

due to this it was giving me error and getting disconnected with state code 133